# How to Convert Pandas filters to Polars Filter?

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to convert the python pandas filter to python polars filter.

1. `df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object] = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object].applymap(lambda x: str(x).strip())`
2. `df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object] = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object].replace('nan', np.NaN)`
3. `df[dateCols['fileColumn']] = pd.to_datetime(df[dateCols['fileColumn']], format=dtpattern,                                         errors='raise')`

can Someone convert these three pandas filters to polars? Converting the pandas filter to polars is a little bit tricky.

Comment: It may be better to start with code for an example Polars dataframe e.g. `df = pl.DataFrame({...})` and show us the exact final output you want.

Comment: How can we convert that to polars and i also dont have the exact final output.

Comment: Did you read the polars documentation on filtering? Which sections did you try and ultimately not understand well enough to use?

Comment: *1.* Looks like: *"Strip all string columns."* e.g. `.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.strip_chars())` *2.* Looks like: *"Replace 'nan' with np.NaN in all string columns."* - But this doesn't make sense in Polars, because columns are strictly typed and only `float` columns can hold `np.NaN` - so it's unclear what you want to do without seeing an actual example.

Comment: If possible can someone convert those 3 filters to polars?

Comment: As requested by @jqurious, please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without an example, the requested filters don't even make sense in polars.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do what I think you're trying to do (but I agree with comments that you should post a reproducible example)

1.

```py
import polars.selectors as cs
df = df.with_columns(cs.string().str.strip_chars())
```

2. 

```py
import polars.selectors as cs
df.with_columns(pl.when(cs.string() != 'nan').then(cs.string()).otherwise(pl.lit(None)))
```

3. 

```py
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('fileColumn').str.to_datetime(format=dtpattern))
```